# Mocking $mdSideNav in unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-material

I have a simple enough function that closes an $mdSidenav instance in my application

```
function closeSideNav() {
    $mdSidenav('left').close();
}
```

I'm now needing to unit test this, but am having trouble writing an expectation for the `close()` call on $mdSidenav.

I thought about using $provide in my test spec

```
module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$mdSidenav', function(id) {
        return {
            close: jasmine.createSpy('$mdSidenav.close')
        }
    })
});

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$mdSidenav_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $mdSidenav = _$mdSidenav_;
}));

beforeEach(function() {
    vm = $controller('NavbarController', {
        $mdSidenav: $mdSidenav
    });
});

describe('vm.closeSideNav', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        spyOn($mdSidenav, 'close');
        vm.closeSideNav()
    });
    it('should call $mdSidenav.close()', function() {
        expect($mdSidenav.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

This throws a couple of errors:

> Error: close() method does not exist
>
> Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.

Has anyone managed to mock out $mdSidenav and offer me some guidance please?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Based on the suggested answer, I have now updated my test spec to

```
'use strict';
describe('NavbarController', function() {
  var $controller,
    vm,
    $mdSidenav,
    sideNavCloseMock;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app.layout');
    sideNavCloseMock = jasmine.createSpy();
    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('$mdSidenav', function() {
        return function(sideNavId) {
          return {close: sideNavCloseMock}
        }
      })
    });

  });
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$mdSidenav_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $mdSidenav = _$mdSidenav_;
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
    vm = $controller('NavbarController', {
      $mdSidenav: $mdSidenav
    });
  });
  describe('vm.closeSideNav', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      vm.closeSideNav()
    });
    it('should call $mdSidenav.close()', function() {
      expect(sideNavCloseMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

And for a sanity check, my actual controller looks as follows:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.layout')
    .controller('NavbarController', Controller);

  Controller.$inject = ['$mdSidenav'];

  function Controller($mdSidenav) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.closeSideNav = closeSideNav;

    //This only affects the sideNav when its not locked into position, so only on small\medium screens
    function closeSideNav() {
      $mdSidenav('left').close();
    }
  }
})();
```

Unfortunately this still isn't working for me, and I end up with a different error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$mdSidenav('left').close())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

close method doesn't belong to $mdSidenav. $mdSidenav is a function that returns a side nav object. That's why it complains 'close() method does not exist'.

What you can do is mock the $mdSidenav to return an object hat has mocked close method, like this: -

```
var sideNavCloseMock;
beforeEach(module(function($provide){
    sideNavCloseMock = jasmine.createSpy();
    $provide.factory('$mdSidenav', function() {
        return function(sideNavId){
            return {close: sideNavCloseMock};
        };
    });
}));
```

then do

```
it('should call $mdSidenav.close()', function() {
    expect(sideNavCloseMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @sdfacre, I have tried this but now get a different error - `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$mdSidenav('left').close())` Any idea why this may be the case?

Comment: umm..interesting, can you print out the sidenav object on console and check if the close function is a spy? i.e. console.log($mdSidenav('left')); or console.log($mdSidenav('left').close); in your console. What jasmine version are you using?

Comment: `console.log($mdSidenav('left'))` returns `function (sideNavId) { ... }`, but `console.log($mdSidenav('left').close)` returns `undefined`. I'm using karma-jasmine and am on the latest version - 0.3.8

Comment: So it's odd that the close function is not being found at all, it's in an object that should be being returned, any thoughts on what could be up here?

Comment: umm...what about console.log($mdSidenav)? Must be something wrong, as console.log($mdSidenav('left')) should return an object, rather than a function.

Comment: `console.log($mdSidenav)` gives me back `function () { ... }`

Comment: My code is still the same as my recent update I made in my original question

Comment: just created this plunker, please check http://plnkr.co/edit/7EDGevhm0UUfu0eYtYnE?p=preview

Comment: OK, I have just realised having now compared with your plunkr that I was using `$provide.value` and not `$provide.factory`! I feel very stupid, but that thanks for taking the time to look into this and going to the trouble of making that plunkr too :)

Comment: If you want to capture the argument (e.g. `mdSidenav('left').close`), use `return { close: sideNavId.bind(null, sideNavId) };`